# DATETIME plus Minutes from table

Tags: datetime, foxpro, visual-foxpro

How do you add minutes to a DATETIME field?

```
08/12/2013 11:00:00 PM + 120 minutes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the add (+) symbol but the value is added in seconds.
120 minutes is 7200 seconds.

```
NewDateTime = OldDateTime + 7200
```

Or, for coding clarity as pointed out by [Tamar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259592/tamar-e-granor):

```
NewDateTime = OldDateTime + (120 * 60)
```

Comment: Agree, but I'd write it as 120*60, for clarify.